# Is it possible to pass a method as a function argument?

Tags: python

I want to know if I can use a method like `isalnum` as argument in a fucntion.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
from curses.ascii import isalpha, isdigit

def vali(string,method):
    for i in string:
        if i.method is True:
            return 'yes'

s = input()
print(vali(s))
```

Comment: You can pass a _function_ as an argument, or the _name_ of a method (as a string). `i.method` is literally accessing an attribute _named "method"_. But when you call `vali` you're only passing one parameter anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't you at least need to supply an argument for `method`?

Comment: yes, the code only runs because he doesn't access `method`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is very much possible

```py
from curses.ascii import isalpha, isdigit

def vali(string, method):
    for i in string:
        if method(i) is True:
            return 'yes'

s = input()
print(vali(s, isdigit))
```

It also works for the built-in member functions [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) & co. In the example below I've simplified your code somewhat.

```py
def vali(s, method):
    return 'yes' if method(s) else None

s = '123'
print(vali(s, str.isdigit))
```

Comment: There is no method involved here, just functions (that happen to have the same names as some string methods), so that doesn't really answer the question.